# FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). CRAZY

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.init({
    appID       : 'my app id is here',
    channelUrl  : '//myappname.herokuapp.com/channel.php',
    status      : true,
    cookie      : true,
    xfbml       : true,
    frictionlessRequests: true
});

// Additional auth


};


 (function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Ok so, that's my scripts.js file, and I HAVE included fb-root to my pagebody, for some reason when loading the page, its logging:

FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

Twice, in the call to all.js line 52, any ideas whats going on?

Comment: first thing, you include fb-root in body and here in javascript file you used 'facebook-jssdk' and can you put full code, what you wrote for Facebook connect

Comment: thats the way it works, it was only a capital letter wrong, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how i make it:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    if (FB.init) return;
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId: 'your app ID', // App ID from the App
        //channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel.html',
        //This to get the user details back from Facebook
        //scope: 'id,name,gender,user_birthday,email', etc
        status: true, // check the login status upon init?
        cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });
}
```

At the end of HTML Body...

```
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

...Or maybe you might use fb embeded iframe
[Facebook Like Button Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)